# Ansible systemd mount dependency

Tags: ansible, systemd

I use Ansible to deploy a systemd unit file to all the servers in an estate and enable it to start on boot.  On some of those servers, the binary defined in the unit file is on a different filesystem.  This requires the unit file to have a dependency on that filesystem being mounted.  E.g.:

```
[Unit]
Description = Start the widget
After = network.target usr.mount

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/widget

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Currently the unit file is deployed by Ansible as a static file, using the `ansible.builtin.copy` module.  Is there a way I can convert this to a template and append the mountpoint to `After =` if `/usr` is a mountpoint?

Comment: Does "/usr" translate to "usr.mount" automagically or is there any mapping? e.g. there might be also "/usr/local/" mount point.

Comment: @VladimirBotka it appears to translate by replacing / with -.  E.g. /usr/local becomes usr-local.mount.  Running `systemctl list-units --type=mount` reveals them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible fact *ansible_mounts* keeps the list of the mount points. Let's use the following vars for testing

```yaml
    widgets:
      - /usr/local/apps/widget
      - /usr/share/apps/widget
      - /scratch/apps/widget
    my_ansible_mounts:
      - mount: /
      - mount: /boot/efi
      - mount: /usr
      - mount: /usr/local
    root:
      - /
```

Create a dictionary of widgets and related mount points, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _mlist: []
    - set_fact:
        _mlist: "{{ _mlist + [{'dict': item.0, 'mount': item.1}] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ widgets }}"
        - "{{ my_ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|difference(root) }}"
      when: item.0|regex_search('^' ~ item.1) != None
    - set_fact:
        _mdict: {}
    - set_fact:
        _mdict: "{{ _mdict|combine({item.0: item.1|
                                            map(attribute='mount')|
                                            map('regex_replace', '/', '-')|
                                            list}) }}"
      loop: "{{ _mlist|groupby('dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _mdict:
    /usr/local/apps/widget:
    - -usr
    - -usr-local
    /usr/share/apps/widget:
    - -usr
```

Then the flow should be trivial, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% if _mdict[item]|default([])|length > 0 %}
          [Unit]
          Description = Start the widget
          After = network.target{% for i in _mdict[item] %} {{ i[1:] }}.mount{% endfor %}


          {% endif %}
          [Service]
          Type = simple
          ExecStart = {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ widgets }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=/usr/local/apps/widget) => 
  msg: |-
    [Unit]
    Description = Start the widget
    After = network.target usr.mount usr-local.mount
  
    [Service]
    Type = simple
    ExecStart = /usr/local/apps/widget
ok: [localhost] => (item=/usr/share/apps/widget) => 
  msg: |-
    [Unit]
    Description = Start the widget
    After = network.target usr.mount
  
    [Service]
    Type = simple
    ExecStart = /usr/share/apps/widget
ok: [localhost] => (item=/scratch/apps/widget) => 
  msg: |-
    [Service]
    Type = simple
    ExecStart = /scratch/apps/widget
```

To test the real stuff, in the code, replace *my_ansible_mounts* with *ansible_mounts* and fit the *widgets* and *hosts* to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use *template* task and in *src* template task have a condition to print required block based on a condition. You can pass a varible to *template* task and make a decision based on it, ie. you first check if that filesystem is needed in a task, then generate file based on the template task.